# Naming convention for multiword view files in Yii?

Tags: yii, naming-conventions

If I have a view with two or more words, e.g.:

```
public function actionApprovalQueue()
```

what is the naming convention of the view file itself?

```
approval-queue.php
approvalQueue.php
approvalqueue.php
??
```

The documentation on [Conventions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.convention) only says:

> View files should be named after the view name. For example, the *index*
>   view is in the *index.php* file.

which gives no clue about views with two or more words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to naming conventions, it comes down to what suits your organisation, or what is followed in your organisation, or what the rest of your team decides. The key is **consistency** throughout your code base.

I would say go with the dash(hyphen), because variables are generally named `$xyzAbc` or `$xyz_abc`. So it would make sense to use `approval-queue.php`.

Definitely do not go for `approvalqueue.php`.

Edit: Read more about [Yii's conventions here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.convention).

Comment: Ok wasn't sure if there was an official Yii stance on naming them.  All the examples I've seen have been one-word view files.

Answer (score 1):

Yii recommends naming variables, functions and class types in camel case which capitalizes the first letter of each word in the name and joins them without spaces. Variable and function names should have their first word all in lower-case, in order to differentiate from class names (e.g. $basePath, runController(), LinkPager). For private class member variables, it is recommended to prefix their names with an underscore character (e.g. $_actionList).

Because namespace is not supported prior to PHP 5.3.0, it is recommended that classes be named in some unique way to avoid name conflict with third-party classes. For this reason, all Yii framework classes are prefixed with letter "C".

A special rule for controller class names is that they must be appended with the word Controller. The controller ID is then defined as the class name with first letter in lower case and the word Controller truncated. For example, the PageController class will have the ID page. This rule makes the application more secure. It also makes the URLs related with controllers a bit cleaner (e.g. /index.php?r=page/index instead of /index.php?r=PageController/index).